# Accidently delete derby.log and metastore_db folder in Spark, now tables won't save

Tags: database, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-warehouse

Currently, I'm working on an exercise with requires creating a Database and tables inside PySpark and working with them. The problem is I created a db before, so I decide to delete all the related things (`spark-warehouse folder`, `metastore_db folder`, `derby.log file`) before starting a new one.

Now when I first created a new database and new tables with the below code, it works fire.

```
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS asm1_db")
spark.sql("USE asm1_db")

dfQ1.write.bucketBy(2, "Id").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("asm1_db.tableQ1")
dfA1.write.bucketBy(2, "ParentId").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("asm1_db.tableA1")
```

But the table and the database won't save. For example the below code:

```
spark.sql("USE asm1_db") => Can't find the database
```

I have to create the database again, even so, the tables won't save

```
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS asm1_db")
spark.sql("USE asm1_db")
spark.sql("select Id from tableq1").show() => Can't find the table tableq1
```

When I check the folder structure on Pycharm the `spark-warehouse folder` and all the db/tables are still there
[image: spark-warehouse]

I have to run the whole write data to the table again, but the data is very big so I don't want to run that every time. I know that **saveAsTable** method create a **Permanent Table**, not **Temporary**

I think the problem is because I delete the `metastore_db folder`, `derby.log file` before. So is there anyway to restore them? I though it will recreate every time I create a new Database.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out in the SparkSession creation code. You have to add .enableHiveSupport(). For example

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("SparkSQLTableDemo") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```